# Python found URL is invalid

Tags: python, url

Hi there I have following Problem:

I extracted a list of URL's from a .txt file with Python using this:

```
 import re

with open('html.txt') as f:
    urls = f.read()
    links = re.findall('"((http)s?://.*?)"', urls)
for url in links:
    print(url[0])
```

And the Output contains for some files following:

```
https://url.com/?download_file=259&#038;order=wc_order_xDxDxD&#038;email=testmail%40gmail.com&#038;key=1234-1234-1234-1234-8c368abd9c22
```

**PROBLEM IS:**

as you see it printed out "#038;" I'm thinking that translates into "&" but there is already a "&" infront of that and if I follow the Link its invalid.

However if I delete all "#038;" the Link works just fine.

How can I print them so that I dont have "#038;" inside and the Link works?

Thanks so much

Comment: Here is a sample of a Link in the .txt file: 


      <a href="https://urlcom/?download_file=259&#038;order=wc_order_BLABLABLA&#038;email=test%40gmail.com&#038;key=1234-1234-1234-1234-12345567" class="woocommerce-MyAccount-downloads-file button alt">PRODUCT 1</a>     </td>
       </tr>

Comment: exact data would give away confidential information, sorry. The problem is alrady solved though it was a encoding issue. Thank you!

Comment: Is the data HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a url encoding issue.
Since, you are only printing, you can use string replace function.

```
for url in links:
    url[0].replace("#038","")
```

Comment: man thanks so much! U dont know how long i've been struggeling for this simple solution :D thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there &#038 = &

[HTML ACIIcharacters](http://www.nationalfinder.com/html/char-asc.htm)